# In Star Trek TNG's episode, "The Neutral Zone," how were the frozen dead people revived if they died BEFORE they were frozen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, cryogenics

Surely doctors in the *Star Trek* universe don't have the power to bring the dead back to life? If so, why wasn't this power used on other dead characters? Why wasn't this incredible power explored in other episodes if they do indeed have it?

It's made clear in the episode by Dr. Crusher that the people found in cryogenic chambers were dead before they were frozen. These are not "sleeping" people in stasis, they are corpses that have been dead and frozen for hundreds of years.

How was she able to bring these long-dead bodies back to life?

Comment: Is there any indication what they died of, or how quickly they were frozen after?  There are lots of people walking around today who "died" of cardiac arrest, and were resuscitated.

Comment: Their corticostimulators seem to work a bit better than our defiblaraters at resuscitating people who are beyond our current definition of 'dead.' That goal post moves as technology advances, as it is a process more than an event. If they were frozen beyond 1980s goal post, but before 2300s goal post they can correct the problems they had, and reverse the process they way they normally do for a phaser shot

Comment: "What's life but nature's way of keeping meat fresh?" - Doctor

Comment: Because they were [_mostly dead_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbE8E1ez97M)

Answer (score 10):

They were frozen "*at the moment of death*", when, even with modern-day technology they could have theoretically been revived. Their deaths were caused by (in order) "*a heart problem*", "*an advanced case of emphysema and extensive liver damage*" and "*an embolism*". All of those are apparently easily correctable with the technology available in the 24th century which means that they only had to unfreeze them.

> **BEVERLY:** *Exactly. Cryonics. It was a
> kind of fad in the late twentieth
> century. People feared dying.
> It terrified them. **At the moment
> of death, they would be frozen,**
> so that later... some time in the
> future, when presumably medical
> science had a cure for whatever
> killed them, they would be thawed
> back to life, healed and sent on
> about their business.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Neutral Zone - Original Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/126.txt)</sup></sub>

Doctor Crusher doesn't go into the process that she used since the Captain (and the audience) don't really need to know how she managed it, other than that she did.

> **BEVERLY:** *Well, he did and they were frozen. I thawed them.*

Comment: The imdb page https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708811/ says they were frozen for 370 years, and memory alpha says the episode took place in 2364  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Neutral_Zone_(episode) which means they were frozen in 1994.  This was in the near future for the air date of the episode (1988).  I think this detail is important because the most limiting piece of cryogenics is how well you manage to preserve the body.  It's probably also supposed to be implied 1994's cryogenics process was better than 1988's.

Comment: @Kai - The whole thing is just handwaved. Cryonics is (apparently) a largely successful way of storing people. We see it used by Khan and his followers too.

Comment: @Valorum  Khan & co were alive in suspended or slowed animation, different from the frozen dead in "The Neutral Zone".

Comment: One of the limitations of cryonics is legal -- since, legally, someone who's frozen solid is dead, it's murder to do that to someone who isn't already dead.  Then, the process takes up to 24 hours after the body (already dead for some hours) is received at the cryonic center.  There was an *L.A. Law* episode about a young woman (with a terminal degenerative nerve disease that would destroy her mind long before it killed her body) seeking to be cryonically preserved *before* her death, which would require a specific court order in California (and most other places).

Comment: is it murder though @ZeissIkon? Maybe more like assisted suicide, but even then, the 
primary conceit of the procedure is that you are not dead nor intend to be dead (of course, intent vs outcome is a different matter....)

Comment: When that *L.A. Law* episode came out, assisted suicide *was* murder, legally speaking, even in places like Netherlands.  And since it's not yet possible to revive a corpsicle, they're still legally dead (no heartbeat, no brain activity, no known path to revival = legally dead).  Not to mention many cryonauts, for financial reasons, chose "cranial preservation" -- freezing only the severed head.  Complicates any path to revival...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Wasn't the head part solved in Futurama?  Jokes aside, I'd assert that for any civilization that has the ability to safely and fully revive a frozen head, the lack of a body won't be an issue.

Comment: In the episode Code of Honor it is stated that doctors can revive a corpse bringing it back to life within 20 minutes of death. Presumably, if the body is frozen within the 20 minutes, it stops the clock. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Honor_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)